# Is it possible to use a texture in OpenGL ES withouth a matrix?

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

[image: This is the result I see]

I am learning OpenGL ES and use for this the book "Lean OpenGL ES for Mobile Game and Graphics Development" written by Mehta. He firstly shows how to build a simple project, goes over and adds orthoMatrix, then 3D, and in the end he explains how to use this all together with a texture. I am wondering if it is possible to use a texture without a matrix. I must say I tried it, the program did not crash, but the the texture was completely scattered and disorted - as if the vertexData was wrong. So my first question is if it is teoretically possible?

**UPDATE 1**

This code below represents an application which is able to show the camera preview on a texture. With the use of a matrix it works fine, but the use without a matrix results in the screen as shown on the picture.

**this is the texture vertex shader and the texture fragment shader**.

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;
void main()
{
v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES u_TextureUnit;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;
void main()
{
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
}
```

**The texture loader**

```
public class TextureHelper {


    public static final int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;

    public static int loadTexture() {
        final int[] textureObjectsId = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureObjectsId, 0);

        if (textureObjectsId[0] == 0 ) {
            return 0;
        }

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureObjectsId[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);

        return textureObjectsId[0];
```

**The locations and uniforms**

```
public class TextureShaderProgram extends ShaderProgram {

    private final int uTextureUnitLocation;
    // Attribute locations
    private final int aPositionLocation;
    private final int aTextureCoordinatesLocation;



    public TextureShaderProgram(Context context) {
        super(context, R.raw.texture_vertex_shader, R.raw.texture_fragment_shader);

        uTextureUnitLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, U_TEXTURE_UNIT);

        aPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);

        aTextureCoordinatesLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, A_TEXTURE_COORDINATES);
    }


    public void setUniforms(int textureId) {
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(uTextureUnitLocation, 0);
    }

    public int getPositionAttributeLocation() {
        return aPositionLocation;
    }
    public int getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation() {
        return aTextureCoordinatesLocation;
    }

}
```

**The vertexData (triangle fan)**

```
public class Table {

    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);

    private static final float[] VERTEXDATA = {


            0f, 0f,         0.5f, 0.5f, //middle
            -0.5f, -0.8f,    1f, 0.1f,//bottom left
            0.5f, -0.8f,    1f, 0.9f, //bottom right
            0.5f, 0.8f,     0f, 0.9f,//top right
            -0.5f, 0.8f,    0f, 0.1f, // top left
            -0.5f, -0.8f,   1f, 0.1f, // bottom left

    };
```

Do you need more? Leave comment so I can post the rest if needed.

Comment: The `STRIDE` is calculated incorrectly. You need to multiply the sum of all components' floats by a float size, but now the closing parenthesis is in wrong place, so only texture coordinate component count is multiplied.

Comment: thanks for the help. It worked! Have a good day!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will normally need some form of transform to animate the vertices in your scene. This is nearly always a matrix, because they can efficiently represent any desirable transform, but it doesn't have to be.

It is rare for the texture coordinate itself to be modified by a matrix - normally the texture is "fixed" on the model so the coordinate is just passed through the vertex shader without modification.

Comment: Okay, so teoretically it is possible. Do you have any ready example on how to use it? Because in my project I am leaving everything out except the texture part and as I said the texture rectangle looks completely deformed. Is there any different and special approach to do it? See my updates maybe they will clear up more

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of what you are getting on screen, and how you are setting up the code in the application. The shaders are unlikely to be the problem here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example